# Get time at a different time zone

Tags: time-date

I want to get the time at a different time zone.  I have noticed `world-clock`, which to set up needs one to configure `world-clock-list`.  The problem is what to write in `world-clock-list`.  There is the shell command `tzselect`, from which the information in `world-clock-list` could possibly be used.

Need help designing this thing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `world-clock` function is a user–interface that shows the current time in one or more time zones. You shouldn’t mess with its configuration though, because that is for the user to decide.

Besides, you don’t need it. Just call `current-time-string` which takes a time zone specifier as an optional argument. Then display that however you like.

Definitely read chapter 41.5 Time of Day and chapter 41.6 Time Zone Rules, for more information.

Comment: How can I get the list of Time Zone strings for the different time zones ?

Comment: You don’t want the whole list, there are thousands of them.